# NavBar / Dropdown bug on Safari

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm coding a complete site for a friends without any framework/CMS. That's like a challenge for me because I'm just a student and he asked me to do something I didn't know all of that but I did it :D

I'm just having a little bug in the mobile version of the site, the dropdown is buggy on Safari.

If you want to try to see the problems there is the minimal code html and CSS.

[There's here a link to a youtube video which show you the problem.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrtBL1oU1d4&feature=youtu.be)

```css
.navheader {
    height: 98px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

header {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar,
.navbar>.container2 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    height: 98px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
         
.navbar {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
         
.nav-brand {
    font-size: 30.4px!important;
    font-size: 1.90rem!important;
}
         
.nav-right {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
         
.nav-items {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 18.4px;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
         
.nav-items:hover {
    color: #18BC9C;
}

.hoverautre2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.hoverautre2 .lien2 {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.hoverautre2 .lien2:hover {
    color: #009985;
}

.container2 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
}
         
.hamburger {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
         
.hamburger>span {
    display: block;
    top: 14px;
}
         
.hamburger>span,
.hamburger>span:before,
.hamburger>span:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background: #fff;
}
         
.hamburger>span:before {
    content: "";
    top: -8px;
}
         
.hamburger>span:after {
    content: "";
    top: 8px;
    left: 0;
}
         
.burger {
    display: none;
}
         
input.burger[type=checkbox]:checked + label ~ .nav-right {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
            transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    .hoverautre {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .nav-right {
        z-index: -1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 98px;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
                    -ms-grid-row-align: center;
                align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
                flex-direction: column;
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
                transform: translateY(-100%);
        background: #1a1a1a;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .hamburger {
    display: block;
    }

    .nav-brand {
        margin: auto;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
                transform: translateX(30px);
    }
}
```

```html
<header class="navheader">
   <nav class="navbar">
          <div class="container2">
              <a href="#home" class="nav-items nav-brand">AYA DESIGN</a>
              <input type="checkbox" id="burger" class="burger">
              <label for="burger" class="hamburger">
                  <span></span>
              </label>
              <div class="nav-right">
               <a href="#port" class="nav-items">Portfolio</a>
               <a href="#about" class="nav-items">About me</a>
                  <a href="#contact" class="nav-items">Contact</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Safari for Windows.

The last version of Safari on Windows was 5.x.x, and has since been discontinued.
Apple has also removed all downloads of Safari for the Windows platform, making Safari a macOS only program.

The current version for Safari on macOS however, is 10.x.x. and your code works as expected as seen in this screen recording: https://c.flm.pw/2017-04/M6gYd.mp4